# What is the best way to find y coordinates of point with specified x value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am, usinf python an numpy array. I want to find all y coordinates of point with specified x coordinate. I use this:

```
[it[1] for it in arrP if it[0] == specX]
```

is there better way?

Comment: Could you give a sample input / output?

Comment: What is the array shape? because it looks like if it's a 2D array you just need the length or the sub-array at index X? or am I not understanding your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]])

# select x in arr with x[0] == 1, and slice out x[1]
arr[arr[:, 0] == 1][:, 1]
```

Outputs

```
array([2, 3])
```

Comment: Try to avoid index chaining. `arr[arr[:, 0] == 1, 1]` is twice as fast for larger arrays.